# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when starting application in Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, frameworks, websphere-8

I'm trying to build a Spring application with RAD 9.5 and deploy in Websphere 8.5. When starting application I get this problem :

```
problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:853)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:763)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
```

I try to find with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and it's reference to spring-2.0.6.jar. But I don't have any idea to fix this error.

Comment: The full stack would be helpful to understand the context that this error comes from.  Anyway, just because you see the spring jar in your workspace doesn't mean it's available to your application at runtime.  Is the spring jar packaged in your application?  If not, do you have the spring jar in a shared library instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I make share library in webpshere console for JSF handler and put spring jar in WebContent\WEB-INF\lib as follow : spring-2.0.6.jar
spring-aop-2.0.6.jar
spring-bean-2.0.6.jar
spring-core-2.0.6.jar

Comment: As requested, please post the full stack trace.  With the full stack trace, someone familiar with the WebSphere Application Server class loaders can better detect whether you have mispackaged some JAR in your application.